# Why subscripting is not allowed on AnyObject in Swift 2.2?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7.3

I wonder why subscripting is not allowed on `AnyObject` in `Swift 2.2(Xcode 7.3)` suddenly and showing error " **Ambiguous use of 'subscript'** ".

Below is my code which was working fine previously:

```
func sampleMethod() {
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sampleFunction", withParameters: nil) { (response, error) -> Void in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            return
        }
        
        if let records = response as? [AnyObject] { // Valid response
            for record in records {
                if let activeCount = record["activeCount"] as? Int {
                    print("activeCount: \(activeCount)")
                }
                
                if let persons = record["persons"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    for person in persons {
                        if let age = person["age"] as? Int {
                            print("age: \(age)")
                        }
                        if let properties = person["properties"] as? [AnyObject] {
                            for property in properties {
                                if let propertyName = property["name"] as? String {
                                    print("propertyName: \(propertyName)")
                                }
                                if let propertyValue = property["value"] as? String {
                                    print("propertyValue: \(propertyValue)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid response")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is my code which is working now in `Swift 2.2` after I changed `AnyObject` to `[String: AnyObject]`:

```
func sampleMethod() {
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sampleFunction", withParameters: nil) { (response, error) -> Void in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            return
        }
        
        if let records = response as? [[String: AnyObject]] { // Valid response
            for record in records {
                if let activeCount = record["activeCount"] as? Int {
                    print("activeCount: \(activeCount)")
                }
                
                if let persons = record["persons"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for person in persons {
                        if let age = person["age"] as? Int {
                            print("age: \(age)")
                        }
                        if let properties = person["properties"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            for property in properties {
                                if let propertyName = property["name"] as? String {
                                    print("propertyName: \(propertyName)")
                                }
                                if let propertyValue = property["value"] as? String {
                                    print("propertyValue: \(propertyValue)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid response")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Below are the screenshots of series of errors solved while I’m changing `AnyObject` to `[String: AnyObject]`:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Any idea on why subscripting is not allowed on `AnyObject` in Swift 2.2?

Comment: Which other libraries are you using? Is it possible some other library is defining the `[]` operator? I cannot reproduce your issue on a clean project.

Comment: I'm using "Parse" framework.

Comment: Since you know the more specific `Dictionary` type why do you use the less specific `AnyObject`? The basic concept of Swift encourages the developers to be as type specific as possible.

Comment: I would argue that it was a bug before to allow subscripting an AnyObject instance.

Comment: @vikingosegundo It actually is a compilation error in Swift - until you import `Foundation`, which probably has some `[]` operator definition for `AnyObject`.

Comment: @vadian: I can't make sure i'll get Dictionary from server always. So the response is AnyObject initially, i'm checking whether it's Dictionary just to make sure that i'm getting correct response.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can't reproduce the issue. This compiles and runs fine for me in Xcode 7.3 (Swift 2.2):

```
var records = [AnyObject]()
records.append(["howdy":"hello"])
for record in records {
    if let x = record["howdy"] {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

I would therefore have to guess that the issue you are seeing is introduced by some library you are using, such as Parse. There most be some other definition of subscripting (perhaps of `objectForKeyedSubscript:`) that is present.

But second, you should never have been doing this in the first place. Swift is all about strict typing. Subscripting an AnyObject is daft, just as sending *any* message to an AnyObject is. Even if you can get away with it, you shouldn't be doing it. There are sane ways to make sure what you're getting is a dictionary and to cast to a dictionary *before* you subscript. Use them.